# jQuery Selector Problem (All Children inside Div)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to attach a click function that adds a CSS class to **all** anchor tags inside of a specific div. Somehow I can't get jQuery to do this (no JS error either).

The div:

```
<div id="better">
    <a href="1.aspx">One</a>
    <a href="2.aspx">Two</a>
    <a href="3.aspx">Three</a>
</div>
```

My jQuery code (inside of $(document).ready):

```
 $("#better > a").click(function() { $(this).addClass('active'); });
```

I added an alert in my click function to see if it fires, but nothing happens. As I wrote above, I don't get JavaScript errors in the FF error console either.

Help?

**Edit: This is just example code.** Yes it doesn't make sense to change a class when you redirect. I've just simplified my code to the core of what I'm trying to do. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#better a").bind('click', function() { $(this).addClass('active'); });
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. If the above didn't work. Only changes are now ANCHORS selected are **not** direct descendants but any descendants. **.click** is just shorthand for **bind('click', func)** if you look through jQuery source code.

Comment: This could cause unforeseen problems by attaching the click event to unwanted anchor tags.  Without knowing the rest of your markup, make sure there aren't other anchor tags inside "better" that don't need the click event attached

Comment: This worked -- my original code didn't. Not sure why or what the difference is.

Comment: @T B: I only have anchor tags inside the target div that I do want affected. Thank you for pointing out the danger though.

Comment: @Alex: I think the difference is the parent-child selector ">"... it's just something I've noticed because I can't get it to work for me properly, so I always just resort to ".find()" or just using a space.

Comment: @fudgey: That's true. I can do the .click (instead of bind) as well. The difference was indeed the parent child selector.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking.. you want to end up with this?

```
<div id="better">
    <a href="1.aspx" class="active">One</a>
    <a href="2.aspx" class="active">Two</a>
    <a href="3.aspx" class="active">Three</a>
</div>
```

If any link in that div was clicked, right? (you did say ALL anchor tags)... then use this:

```
$("#better").click(function() {
 $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alerting works for me. However why would you add a class if you are redirecting to a new page?

Comment: After redirection the class won't matter. If you dont wan't to follow the link try: return false;

Answer (score 0):

Two guesses:

1. Do you maybe have another element on your page with `id="better"`?  ID is supposed to be globally unique, so the selector will only return one of them.
2. Try making your click function return false, to keep the user from following the link.  (Seems strange to add a class when the user is leaving the page, unless maybe the link opens in a new window.)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code at the bottom of the page right before the closing body tag or in a $(document).ready() function.

Using Firebug, you can use console.log() to write out to the javascript console to make sure the selector is actually returning elements. example: console.log($("#better > a").length)